# compiler cannot convert the return type of the function from double to int when i use templates

Tags: c++, templates, casting

This code gives warning about converting from double to int.

```
template <class T>
int f(T x)
{
    return x;    
}

int main()
{
    cout << f(3.5);
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I don't use templates, as the below, it can convert from double to int and print 3.

```
int f(float x)
{
    return x;    
}

int main()
{
    cout << f(3.5);
    return 0;    
}
```

Although, it can compile nontemplated sample, the templated sample cannot be compiled. I wonder why the compiler cannot make conversion when template is used.

Why can't the compiler convert the return type of the function from double to int when I use templates??

Comment: Your non-template version is not equivalent. `3.5` has type `double`, not `float`.

Comment: yeah , in both codes it gives the same warning , but in templated function it also gives error and cannot be compiled. However nontemplate sample can be compiled and run

Comment: What **error** does the first code sample give and on which compiler?

Comment: "instantiated from here " for line cout . And warning that i said . It can't compile.

Comment: @user1308990: "instantiated from here" is not an error. It's the compiler tracing back the template instantiation context.

Comment: What compiler? Can't reproduce on GCC 4.6.3.

Comment: @user1308990, you need to be very explicit about the error message, copy/paste would be ideal. And tell us which compiler.

Answer (score 2):

It can, but it might also suspect that you made a mistake. A warning is just that - telling you that there *might* be a problem.

You can tell the compiler that the conversion is on purpose by adding a cast

```
return static_cast<int>(x);
```

Comment: Although, it can compile nontemplated sample , the templated sample cannot be compiled. I wonder why the compiler cannot make conversion when template is used

Comment: It can, but it doesn't want to. :-) Obviously, the compiler writer is more concerned about possible errors in templated code. A warning is just an indication that there *might* be a problem. By spelling the conversion out explicitly, you tell the compiler what your intentions are.

Comment: When we say explicitly , it's OK. But it cannot convert automatically. I think it's a harsh rule of C++

Comment: It *can* convert, it just also wants to tell you that there *might* be a problem. Not all `T`'s are implicitly convertible to an `int`, right?

Comment: @user1308990 - It's your compiler, not C++. Multiple versions of GNU C++, multiple versions of clang have no problem with your code.

Comment: Then , why can't it compile? Does a warning cause "not compiling"?

Comment: @user - If you compile with `-Werror`, all warnings will be treated as errors and stop the compilation. Otherwise you are free to ignore the warnings. It is up to you.